# DetailViewクラスを呼ぶ時にURLにIDを渡すことができない

Tags: python, python3, django

Mac, Python3, Djangoを利用して、ローカル環境でWEBアプリを開発しています。

URLを `http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/1/` としてDetailViewクラスを呼ぶと、下記のエラーが出ます。（データベースには[ID1]でデータがあることは確認しています。）

```
Generic detail view DetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

どのように解決すれば良いか、教えていただけないでしょうか？

実行環境
Mac: mojave 10.14.6
Python: 3.7.5
Django: 2.2.2

関係するコードは

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

views.py
＊[pk_url_kwarg = 'id']とoverrideして変数名を[PK]から[id]としています。

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views import generic
from .models import Db

class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):

  model = Db
  template_name = 'detail.html'
  pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
```

**これまでに試した事**
①[int:pk]の書き方を変える
urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
            #path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
            #↓
            path('detail/(?P<pk>\d+)$/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
        ]
```

結果

```
Page not found (404)
```

②overrideしないで、デフォルトのPKを使用
views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views import generic
from .models import Db

class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):

        model = DbVegetableInfo
        template_name = 'detail.html'
        #↓
        # pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
```

結果

```
Reverse for 'detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

③[LoginRequiredMixin]を継承しない
views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views import generic
from .models import Db

#class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
#↓
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):

  model = Db
  template_name = 'detail.html'
  pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
```

結果

```
Generic detail view DetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の方法で解決出来ましたので、紹介します。
なお、DetailViewでoverrideして、idを利用する方法（↓）は、

```
pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
```

エラーが出て解決できなかったので、デフォルトのpkを使う方法で対応しました。

---

①urls.py,views.pyの設定
   urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    ]
```

views.py
idは使わず、デフォルトのpkを使用

```
class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):

  model = Db
  template_name = 'detail.html'
```

②hrefタグの調整
この状態でサーバーを動かすと、エラーメッセージが以下のようになる

```
Reverse for 'detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

DetailViewへ遷移する元となるListViewなどのhrefタグを調整して、detail/pk/に対応させる

```
{% for list in object_list %}    
<a href="{% url 'main:detail' list.pk %}">detail</a>
{% endfor %}
```